# AdMob SmartBanner incorrect size even when recreating it in onConfigurationChanged

Tags: android, admob

I'm recreating AdView in onConfigurationChanged method, and it was working fine until now. Now size is not changing when orientation changes. I've tried to use previous version of AdMob SDK, and AppCompat with no luck. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've just realized it's related to https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=202798

So using this code inside onConfigurationChanged as a temporary workaround fixes the problem:

```
getResources().updateConfiguration(config, Resources.getSystem().getDisplayMetrics());
```

Hope it helps.

Answer (score -1):

admob banner sixe can only be a specific size! this would maybe be why this is happening, you shouldnt really need configuration changedsee here https://www.google.co.uk/search?q=admob+banner+size&ie=utf-8&oe=utf-8&gws_rd=cr&ei=y5PpVu_rHYf1avSDgpgM

Banner size
Size (WxH)  Description                  Availability

300x250 IAB Medium Rectangle             Phones and Tablets
468x60  IAB Full-Size Banner             Tablets
728x90  IAB Leaderboard Tablets
Screen width x 32|50|90 Smart Banner     Phones and Tablets

Comment: SmartBanners are "smart" because "smartly" detect the width of the phone in its current orientation, and make the ad view that size: https://developers.google.com/mobile-ads-sdk/android-legacy/docs/admob/smart-banners